# Assigning group permissions using to Azure DevOps CLI

Tags: permissions, azure-devops, command-line-interface

I am trying to assign permissions to the "build administrators" group using the cli.

The specific permission i want to update is the "Delete Team Project" permission.

[image: Valid XHTML]

The documentation is a little difficult to put together since the information is scattered, specially the parts about security tokens and permissions bits.

I am using the az devops security command. The part i am struggling with is getting the **correct** token and the setting the correct permission bits

I know the namespace I want to use. it is the **environment** namespace. Found this out by first checking all the namespaces and finding the guid for the environment namespace.

```
#get list of all namespaces
az devops security permission namespace list -o table

$envnamespace = <guid from above command for the environment namespace>
```

```
# first i set my org and token
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<MYORG>"
$personalToken = "<MY_PERSONAL_TOKE>"
$projectName = "<my_project>"

# login using PAT
$personalToken | az devops login --organization $orgUrl

# set default organisation
az devops configure --defaults organization=$orgUrl

# get the group descriptor ID for the group "build administrators"
$id = az devops security group list --project $projectName --output json --query "graphGroups[?displayName == '$groupID'].descriptor | [0]" -o tsv --verbose

# now i want to add permissions for the group "build administrators"
# but i am not sure what the token should be and what permission bits to use
```

I run the following command to see list the permissions on the group. it returns some tokens but they don't make sense to me. How am i meant to know which token is for what permissions. for example how do i know which token is for "Delete Team Project" permission

```
az devops security permission list --namespace-id $envnamespace --subject $id
```

The aim next is to run the following command to update permissions

```
az devops security permission update --namespace-id $envnamespace --subject $id --token $token2 --allow-bit 4 deny-bit 1 --verbose
```

The --allow-bit and deny-bit i'm not sure exactly what it should be to set the permission to **deny**

any advice on the correct way to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how do I know which token is for "Delete Team Project" permission

Run `az devops security permission namespace list`, the namespaceID of "Delete Team Project" is under the "`Project`" namespace.

You can get the `bit` and the `namespaceID` of the specific `Delete Team Project` namespace (for reference see screenshot shown below).

> How am I meant to know which token is for what permissions

For the tokens, you can refer to [Security tokens for permissions management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/security_tokens?view=azure-devops) for details, there are listed [Token examples for different namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/security_tokens?view=azure-devops#token-examples-for-different-namespaces).

Another example for your reference (reference [jessehouwing's blog](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/)) :

```
az login
az extension add --name "azure-devops"

# Find the group identifier of the group you want to set permissions for

$org = "gdbc2019-westeurope"

# There is a weird edge case here when an Azure DevOps Organization has a Team Project with the same name as the org.
# In that case you must also add a query to filter on the right domain property `?@.domain == '?'`  

$subject = az devops security group list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --scope organization `
    --subject-types vssgp `
    --query "graphGroups[?@.principalName == '[$org]\Project Collection Administrators'].descriptor | [0]"

$namespaceId = az devops security permission namespace list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --query "[?@.name == 'Git Repositories'].namespaceId | [0]"

$bit = az devops security permission namespace show `
    --namespace-id $namespaceId `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --query "[0].actions[?@.name == 'PullRequestBypassPolicy'].bit | [0]"

az devops security permission update `
    --id $namespaceId `
    --subject $subject `
    --token "repoV2/" `
    --allow-bit $bit `
    --merge true `
    --org https://dev.azure.com/$org/
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to add a group to a iteration? I want to give a group permissions on a iteration. I have the command to update the permission once I add them but Im not sure which CLI command is used to add the group to the iteration. fyi im referring to  when you right click a iteration then click security then add group (in the webui)