# AzureDevOps RestAPI does not return groups that are a member of a certain group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm observing strange behaviour of Azure DevOps REST API.
This documentation page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 is saying that "A member is a user or a group added to an account."

But when I try to get members of a certain group like:
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/XXXXX/_apis/GroupEntitlements/YYY/members?api-version=5.1-preview.1

it returns all user members perfectly fine, hoverer no group members of YYY group. At the same time I can see that YYY contains quite lot of groups that are a member of YYY.

At the same time I do not see other API that looks as being able to do what I need.
My personal access token has all 'Read' permissions to all object types.
Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, we can use the API to list all group and get group ID(Group ID in the response body is `originId`)

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Get the one group `subjectDescriptor` via below REST API

Note: `subjectDescriptor` is field `value` in the response body

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/graph/descriptors/{Group ID}
```

[image]

List group member

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Request Body

```
{
  "contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-admin-web.org-admin-members-data-provider"
  ],
  "dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {
      "subjectDescriptor": "{subjectDescriptor}",
      "sourcePage": {
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_settings/groups?subjectDescriptor={subjectDescriptor}",
        "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.collection-admin-hub-route",
        "routeValues": {
          "adminPivot": "groups",
          "controller": "ContributedPage",
          "action": "Execute"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Note: I recommend that you raise the initial issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), they will check it and contact to Product team.

**Update1**

Check group permission and get NamespaceId and Token.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=6.0-preview
```

Request Body

```
{
  "contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-admin-web.org-admin-groups-permissions-pivot-data-provider"
  ],
  "dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {
      "subjectDescriptor": "{subjectDescriptor},
      "sourcePage": {
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/v-viliu/_settings/groups?subjectDescriptor={subjectDescriptor}",
        "routeId": "ms.vss-admin-web.collection-admin-hub-route",
        "routeValues": {
          "adminPivot": "groups",
          "controller": "ContributedPage",
          "action": "Execute"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get descriptor via below [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security%20namespaces/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=6.0
```

[Get group permission detail info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?token={Token}&descriptors={descriptor}&api-version=6.0
```

Note: This is binary code.

[Update group permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/set%20access%20control%20lists?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=6.0
```

We could get the request body through the API above, If you need to change permissions, you only need to change the value of field Allow and Deny.

You could also refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374078/assigning-group-permissions-using-to-azure-devops-cli/58377803#58377803).

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks a lot! But do you observe the same about trying to pull group entitlements like I described in the initial post?

Comment: Thank you for you help, worked for me (I was trying to get the sub group in a group) and I didnt saw the route /Contribution/HierarchyQuery