# How to get subject id of Build Service

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to configure permission in Azure DevOps using az devops cli following this answer ([Assigning group permissions using to Azure DevOps CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374078/assigning-group-permissions-using-to-azure-devops-cli)).

I successes update Force Push to Allow For Contributors group, using this command line:

```
az devops security permission update `
    --id $namespaceId `
    --subject $subject `
    --token "$repoV2" `
    --allow-bit $bit `
    --merge true `
    --org https://dev.azure.com/$org/
```

I extracted subject id by this command:

```
$subject = az devops security group list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --scope organization `
    --subject-types vssgp `
    --query "graphGroups[?@.principalName == 'ForcePush'].descriptor | [0]"
```

[image]

Now I want to do give Contribute (GenericContribute) to ProjectName Build Service (organization), (note: with red question mark in image). It is neither a user nor group, even thus it is under users category. How can I change permission for this using command line?

Note: It will be fine for me if the solution either az devops cli, rest api or graphs api.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

[image]

[image]

---

**Original Answer:**

Refer to this official document so that we will know the namespace id:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/namespace-reference?view=azure-devops

namespace id in your situation is: '2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87'

How to achieve your requirements:

Just Send API call to this:

`https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/AccessControlEntries/2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87`

***Request Method:***

`POST`

***Request Body:***

```
{
    "token": "repoV2/<Project ID>/<repo ID>/",
    "merge": true,
    "accessControlEntries": [
        {
            "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ServiceIdentity;<Organization ID>:Build:<Project ID>",
            "allow": 4,
            "deny": 0,
            "extendedInfo": {
                "effectiveAllow": 4,
                "effectiveDeny": 0,
                "inheritedAllow": 4,
                "inheritedDeny": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

***How to get the above IDs:***

**1, Organization ID.**

I will suggest a simple method here(Of course you can try to use API to get it):

Turn on the browser, press F12 to turn on the debug mode and then go to this place:

`https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/`

After that, search this: `https://spsprodsea2.vssps.visualstudio.com/`

You will get the organization ID here:

[image]

**2, Project ID.**

Just follows this API:

`https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Just search the name in the response and you will get the ID. In this situation, the project build service account is managed via project id.

**3, Repository ID.**

`https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Search the repository name and you will get the ID.

Success on my side:

[image]

Comment: I thump up for a good coverage answer and your effort, those I will wait accepting the answer, hence it did not success me to find org id using the method you mentioned in step 1, I will continue working on it to find a more practical way solving it. and will update more here if and when it sucess.

Comment: @MaythamFahmi Hi Maytham, I hope you are doing well. There is an easy way, after pressing f12, do a simple permission click, and you can capture network traffic analysis, you should get the same request body format as mine. You can get the organization id based on that. I have updated the answer, you can have a check.

Comment: I can confirm it works with your new update, thank you for your effort. was big help.

Answer (score 1):

To get the organization Id dynamically you just have to retrieve the value of the `System.CollectionId` variable as following:

```
$orgId = $(System.CollectionId)
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services

Comment: I have edited your answer and added the documentation link, and thx for the hint of `system.collectionid` which solve only little part of the question. This will only work from Azure DevOps pipeline, it can not consume the value in command line while testing this in Windows or Linux. That said it could be helpful running this in AZDO to get the id and use it in command line. but if our code should run automatically from Azure DevOps it would absolutely solve the problem.