# Set Azure Devops Permissions through CLI in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

To whoever can help me. I greatly appreciate it.

I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374078/assigning-group-permissions-using-to-azure-devops-cli) and am unable to successfully see the update.  My end goal is to stand up new project spaces with default groups with default permissions.  However, one step at a time.

After running the code script, I refresh the Devops permissions page and do not see the field being updated

[image]

even though I see the code completed.

I tried all tokens provided in `az devops security permission list --namespace-id $namespaceId --subject $subject`

[image]

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit=-1
az login --allow-no-subscriptions
az extension add --name "azure-devops"

# Find the group identifier of the group you want to set permissions for

$org = "silverscout"
$proj = "[Test]"

# There is a weird edge case here when an Azure DevOps Organization has a Team Project with the same name as the org.
# In that case you must also add a query to filter on the right domain property `?@.domain == '?'`  

$subject = az devops security group list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --project "$proj" `
    --scope project `
    --subject-types vssgp `
    --query "graphGroups[?@.principalName == '[Test]\NewGroupABC'].descriptor | [0]"


$namespaceId = az devops security permission namespace list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --query "[?@.name == 'Project'].namespaceId | [0]"

$bit = az devops security permission namespace show `
    --namespace-id $namespaceId `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --query "[0].actions[?@.name == 'RENAME'].bit | [0]"

    az devops security permission list `
    --namespace-id $namespaceId `
    --subject $subject  

az devops security permission update `
    --id $namespaceId `
    --subject $subject `
    --token "Masked...." `
    --allow-bit $bit `
    --merge true `
    --org https://dev.azure.com/$org/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Check out my this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73604546/set-azure-devops-permissions-from-azure-cli-and-tokennot-pat-issue-any-azure/73606098#73606098) and the solution is there.

The correct token is `$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/$ProjID`

but the trick is that there is a **$** in it. So if you want to run the command in PowerShell, you need to use

```
`$
```

**to replace `$`. Otherwise, PowerShell will treat $PROJECT as a variable.**

```
az devops security permission update --id $namespaceId --subject $subject --token "`$PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/$ProjID" --allow-bit $bit --merge true --org "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/" -o table
```

Also, you will find all the tokens [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/namespace-reference?view=azure-devops).

Comment: thanks, when I hard coded it I had to put in the `.  However, when I did this for some reason I didn't.                  "Project" 
                    {
                        Write "Using Project Token"
                        $TknQuery = "[?contains(token, 'PROJECT:vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/$ProjID')].token | [0]" 
                        Break
                    } 
    
    
    $Tkn = az devops security permission list `
                --namespace-id $namespaceId `
                --subject $subject `
                --query $TknQuery