# az devops cli from Powershell - Could not cast or convert from System.String to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDescriptor

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to run some Azure DevOps cli commands to create and manage repositories, permissions and similar.

I run these from a PowerShell terminal (Powershell 7.2.6).
I successfully manage to run the following to create a repo;

```
az repos create --name "$Repository" --organization $Organization --project "$Project"
```

But when trying to run the following to set permissions, I get the error "Could not cast or convert from System.String to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDescriptor."

```
az devops security permission update --organization https://dev.azure.com/MYORG/ --id 2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87 --subject MyAzureADGroupName --token repoV2/24123456-eaca-1234-a32b-aa7895da/7123456-a332544r436a-af543-b1123bct546e/ --allow-bit 2 --merge true
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Very much would like to use Powershell to manage this, as it will also be used to create corresponding Azure AD groups etc.

Many thanks!

Comment: Check [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58377803/3949759). Specifically on the way the ID for the group is first retrieved. I get the same error with az cli in bash when i try to use your code, so no issue with powershell here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already were able to solve it, but I had this same issue yesterday. The problem is in the *--subject* part. When you give access to a security group you need to provide the **Descriptor** and not the **Name**. You can find Descriptor for the security group like this:

```
az devops security group list --org https://dev.azure.com/MYORG/ --project 7123456-a332544r436a-af543-b1123bct546e --output table
```

Then to set the permission it would look something like this:

```
az devops security permission update --organization https://dev.azure.com/MYORG/ --id 2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87 --subject vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS0xMDQwODc5MDIwLTMyMjI1ODg0OTUtMjcyOTQ5OTQ4My0zNTQ4MTczMjY4LTEtMzI0MTE5OTQzMS0yMjgxNDc3OTYxLTI5MTQwMTkzNzAtMjczOTQzMTYwMA --token repoV2/24123456-eaca-1234-a32b-aa7895da/7123456-a332544r436a-af543-b1123bct546e/ --allow-bit 2 --merge true
```

Btw, I assume you added the AD group to a security group in Azure DevOps with the same name. Giving an AD group access directly, like you could do for User@email.com, does not work as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-ad-aad-built-in-security-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#add-azure-ad-user-or-group-to-a-built-in-security-group).